# WSS not working on IOS phone and Safari MacOS

Tags: node.js, rtsp

Im using
`rtsp-relay` 
, this module allows you to view an RTSP stream in your web browser using an existing express.js server.

When I use Windows or Android phone it worked. But not working in IOS and macOS Safari.
Log bug on Safari: WebSocket connection to 'wss://domain' failed: there was a bad response from the server.

[image]

My code:

```
const express = require("express");
const https = require("https");
const fs = require("fs");
const rtspRelay = require("rtsp-relay");
const cors = require("cors");
const app = express();
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }), express.json());
const options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync("./__vps_vn.key", "utf8"),
  cert: fs.readFileSync("./star_vps_vn_cert.pem", "utf8"),
};

const server = https.createServer(options, app);

const { proxy, scriptUrl } = rtspRelay(app, server); //, server

//Get
app.ws("/api/stream/:username/:password/:domain/:channel/:port", (ws, req) => {
  proxy({
    url: `rtsp://${req.params.username}:${req.params.password}@${req.params.domain}.kbvision.tv:${req.params.port}/cam/realmonitor?channel=${req.params.channel}&subtype=0`,
    verbose: false,
    transport: "tcp",
    additionalFlags: [
      "-f", // force format
      "hls",
      "-codec:v", // specify video codec (MPEG1 required for jsmpeg)
      "mpeg1video",
      "-r",
      "30", // 30 fps. any lower and the client can't decode it
      "-preset",
      "slow",
      "-crf",
      "18",
      "-b:v",
      "3M",
      "-s",
      "650x450",
    ],
  })(ws);
});

// this is an example html page to view the stream
app.get("/:username/:password/:domain/:channel", (req, res) => {
  if (!req.params.domain.split(":")[1]) {
    res.send("<h1>Params Error</h1>");
    return;
  }
  let domain = req.params.domain.split(":")[0];
  let port = req.params.domain.split(":")[1];
  console.log("Camera is running!");
  res.send(`
  <canvas id='canvas' width='640' height='480'></canvas>
  <script src='${scriptUrl}'>
  </script>
  <script>
    loadPlayer({
      url: 'wss://' + location.host + '/api/stream/${req.params.username}/${req.params.password}/${domain}/${req.params.channel}/${port}',
      canvas: document.getElementById('canvas')
    });
    
  </script>
`);
});

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send("<h1>Hello World!</h1>");
});

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8000;
server.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log("Server is running port " + PORT);
});
```

Help me. I've been trying to solve this problem for weeks but it still doesn't work